# How to use an Error define in one pallet in another pallet

Tags: rust, error

I have a substrate pallet `A` and it has following Errors Defined

```rust
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// Not a coffee
        InvalidCoffee,
    }
```

trait implementation in Pallet `A`

```rust
pub trait A<AccountId, Error> {
 

    fn is_valid_coffee(coffee_id: u32) -> Result<bool, Error>;
}

impl<T: Config> A<AccountIdOf<T>, Error<T>> for Pallet<T> {
     

     
    fn is_valid_coffee(coffee_id: u32) -> Result<bool, Error<T>> {
        Coffee::<T>::get(coffee_id).ok_or(Error::<T>::InvalidCoffee)
    }
}
```

I am using a trait defined in this Pallet `A`  (`is_valid_coffee`) in pallet `B`, it requires the Error defined in Pallet `A`. How to import it to Pallet `B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trait Config: frame_system::Config + another_pallet::Config {}

fn example<T>() -> DispatchError 
where
    T: Config
{
    Err(<another_pallet::Error<T>>::AnotherError)
}
```